# Encoding error when trying to encode decode get request, exercise from PY4E course, in wsl the script will run correctly and print out the romeo.txt

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

```
import socket
mysock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org',80))
cmd='GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data=mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data)<1:
        break
    print(data.decode('utf-8'),end="")
mysock.close
```

This is an example script from the py4e course in coursera. When I run it all I get back is gibberish and what seems to be some HTML stuff. At first I wasn't getting an encoding error with all that info. No longer, don't know why.

When I run the script on WSL (windows linux subsystem) it runs correctly and gets the file.

This is the output from the script run on VSCode in Windows:

yIGBGB75Zrr/vgCUAHz/viy/L+qoZ+rrkHeyAH8nfGCASD+Aj6Op/73wtHFtgEOutAAAAEAEv/nA5MESAATACxAFwMPAAkPEQQUFQIRExFGWRMPDAVGWQwWAD8rABg/K

```
     }

        .container {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 24px 0;
            max-width: 800px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .alert {
            border: 4px solid #F88A1B;
            background-color: #FFEDD0;
            padding: 50px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-start;
        }

        .container_image {
            margin-right: 24px;
            height: 43px;
        }

        .container_text {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 80%;
            padding-left: 15px;

            @media (max-width: 660px) {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        .malicious-download-b {
            color: #3D3C40;
            font-family: 'Kievit Regular';
            font-size: 28px;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            line-height: 34px;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 12px;
            line-height: 34px;
        }

        .url-https-ask-com {
            height: 24px;
            width: 422px;
            color: #555C64;
            font-family: "Open Sans";
            font-size: 16px;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            line-height: 24px;
        }

        .url-bold {
            height: 24px;
            color: #555C64;
            font-family: "Open Sans";
            font-size: 16px;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            line-height: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .this-download-is-pot {
            height: 48px;
            width: 552px;
            color: #3D3C40;
            font-family: "Open Sans";
            font-size: 16px;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            line-height: 24px;
            display: inline;
        }

        .security-warning {
            color: #3D3C40;
            font-family: "Open Sans";
            font-size: 16px;
            letter-spacing: 0;
                        margin-top: 4px;
        }

        .img {
            vertical-align: middle;
            display: inline-block;
            padding-right: 10px;
            height: 35px;
                        width: 100px;
        }

        .logo {
            padding-bottom: 24px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <svg version="1.1" class="img" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                viewBox="0 0 141 45.667" enable-background="new 0 0 141 45.667" xml:space="preserve">
                    <path fill="#E11F27" d="M45.479,43.972c0,0.601-0.486,1.09-1.089,1.09H1.942c-0.601,0-1.088-0.489-1.088-1.09V1.525
                        c0-0.602,0.487-1.09,1.088-1.09H44.39c0.603,0,1.089,0.488,1.089,1.09V43.972z"/>
                    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M36.237,25.981l-0.074-0.081l-2.46,2.336c0.654,0.688,0.625,1.776-0.065,2.428
                        c-0.688,0.652-1.776,0.625-2.43-0.062c-0.079-0.071-0.153-0.147-0.22-0.226c0,0-4.012-4.231-6.619-6.979l9.03-8.57
                        c-5.642-5.314-14.494-5.548-20.016-0.205c-5.52,5.343-6.204,13.995-1.002,20.151l9.493-9.008l6.971,7.348    
                        c0.971,0.922,2.319,1.418,3.708,1.376c1.299-0.037,2.439-0.571,3.296-1.38c1.039-0.979,1.661-2.364,1.65-3.76
                        C37.487,27.883,36.931,26.762,36.237,25.981z M27.733,15.662L13.509,29.159C8.72,20.693,18.744,10.549,27.733,15.662z"/>
                    <g>
                        <path d="M78.64,36.59l-3.29-9.946H64.686l-3.328,9.946h-2.572l9.53-28.098h3.517l9.492,28.098H78.64z M71.379,14.921
                            c-0.492-1.437-0.87-2.799-1.21-4.349h-0.265c-0.378,1.55-0.756,2.912-1.21,4.349l-3.252,9.416h9.113L71.379,14.921z"/>
                        <path d="M91.992,36.59h-3.441l-7.072-20.535h2.685l4.613,13.879c0.567,1.739,1.021,3.327,1.475,4.953h0.075 
                            c0.492-1.626,0.908-3.176,1.475-4.953l4.575-13.879h2.685L91.992,36.59z"/>
                        <path d="M103.981,12.047V7.358h2.533v4.689H103.981z M103.981,36.59V16.055h2.495V36.59H103.981z"/>        
                        <path d="M115.894,19.648V36.59h-2.42V16.055h2.42v1.664c2.42-1.739,5.333-2.193,7.715-2.193v2.231
                            C121.339,17.757,118.163,18.287,115.894,19.648z"/>
                        <path d="M138.472,36.59v-1.475c-1.437,0.87-3.782,1.966-6.845,1.966c-4.008,0-6.127-1.815-6.127-5.899v-0.568
                            c0-5.219,3.365-6.277,9.379-6.277h3.478v-1.739c0-4.009-0.869-4.954-5.446-4.954c-2.004,0-3.705,0.151-6.013,0.416v-1.815
                            c1.929-0.341,3.554-0.719,6.202-0.719c6.543,0,7.753,2.231,7.753,7.072V36.59H138.472z M138.358,26.266h-3.478
                            c-4.955,0-6.921,0.681-6.921,4.348v0.719c0,2.836,1.588,3.819,4.159,3.819c2.571,0,5.106-1.135,6.24-1.853V26.266z"/>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            <span id="translate_securityWarning" class="security-warning"> - Security Warning</span>
        </div>

        <div class="alert">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="64px" height="56px">
                <g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero">
                    <path fill="#FF9F01"
                        d="M15.86 13.47L8.84 1.488A.975.975 0 0 0 8 1a.975.975 0 0 0-.84.488L.14 13.47c-.182.312-.187.7-.013 1.017.174.317.5.513.853.513h14.04c.353 0 .68-.196.853-.513a1.035 1.035 0 0 0-.014-1.017z" />
                    <path fill="#FFF"
                        d="M8.005 11.4c.429 0 .795.364.795.8 0 .426-.366.8-.795.8a.803.803 0 0 1-.805-.8c0-.436.345-.8.805-.8zm0-6.4c.43 0 .795.24.795.665 0 1.296-.154 3.16-.154 4.456 0 .337-.376.479-.64.479-.354 0-.652-.142-.652-.48 0-1.296-.154-3.159-.154-4.455 0-.425.353-.665.805-.665z" />
                </g>
            </svg>

            <div class="container_text">
                <p id="translate_blockedDomain" class="malicious-download-b">Blocked domain</p>
                <p><span id="translate_url" class="url-bold">URL:</span><span id="threatUrl" class="url-https-ask-com">  </span></p>
                <p class="this-download-is-pot">
                    <span id="translate_blacklistedDomain">This is a blacklisted domain in your antivirus settings.</span>       
                    <br />
                    <span id="translate_accessUnblock">To access it, unblock the domain.</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
                /* Polyfill - String.prototype.startsWith */
                if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
                        Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'startsWith', {
                                value: function(search, rawPos) {
                                        var pos = rawPos > 0 ? rawPos|0 : 0;
                                        return this.substring(pos, pos + search.length) === search;
                                }
                        });
                }

        /* Polyfill - Array.prototype.forEach */
                if (!Array.prototype['forEach']) {
                  Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback, thisArg) {

                        if (this == null) { throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.forEach called on null or undefined'); }        

                        var T, k;
                        var O = Object(this);
                        var len = O.length >>> 0;

                        if (typeof callback !== "function") { throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function'); }

                        if (arguments.length > 1) { T = thisArg; }

                        k = 0;
                        while (k < len) {
                          var kValue;
                          if (k in O) {
                                kValue = O[k];
                                callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
                          }
                          k++;
                        }
                  };
                }

        /* Polyfill - NodeList.prototype.forEach */
                if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
                   NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
                }

                var supportedLanguages = ["en", "de", "es", "fr", "it", "ja", "nl", "pt", "ru", "tr", "zh-CN", "zh-TW"];
                var browserLang = navigator.language;
                var tempLang = "";
                if (browserLang == "zh-TW")
                {
                        tempLang = browserLang;
                }
                else if (browserLang.startsWith("zh"))
                {
                        tempLang = "zh-CN";
                }
                else
                {
                        tempLang = browserLang.split('-')[0];
                }

                var translationLang = "en"; //default;
                supportedLanguages.forEach(function(supportedLanguage) {
                        if(supportedLanguage == tempLang)
                        {
                                translationLang = tempLang;
                        }
                });

                var urlString = "";

                var translations = {
                        "en_translate_securityWarning": " - Security Warning",
                        "de_translate_securityWarning": " - Sicherheitswarnung",
                        "es_translate_securityWarning": " - Aviso de seguridad",
                        "fr_translate_securityWarning": " - Avertissement de sécurité",
                        "it_translate_securityWarning": " - Avviso di sicurezza",
                        "ja_translate_securityWarning": " - セキュリティの警告",
                        "nl_translate_securityWarning": " - Beveiligingswaarschuwing",
                        "pt_translate_securityWarning": " - Aviso de segurança",
                        "ru_translate_securityWarning": " - Предупрежд. безопасности",
                        "tr_translate_securityWarning": " - Güvenlik Uyarısı",
                        "zh-CN_translate_securityWarning": " - 安全警告",
                        "zh-TW_translate_securityWarning": " - 安全警告",

                        "en_translate_blockedDomain": "Blocked domain",
                        "de_translate_blockedDomain": "Domain blockiert",
                        "es_translate_blockedDomain": "Dominio bloqueado",
                        "fr_translate_blockedDomain": "Domaine bloqué",
                        "it_translate_blockedDomain": "Dominio bloccato",
                        "ja_translate_blockedDomain": "ブロックされたドメイン",
                        "nl_translate_blockedDomain": "Geblokkeerd domein",
                        "pt_translate_blockedDomain": "Domínio bloqueado",
                        "ru_translate_blockedDomain": "Заблокирован домен",
                        "tr_translate_blockedDomain": "Engellenen etki alanı",
                        "zh-CN_translate_blockedDomain": "已阻止的域",
                        "zh-TW_translate_blockedDomain": "封鎖的網域",

                        "en_translate_url": "URL:",
                        "de_translate_url": "URL:",
                        "es_translate_url": "URL:",
                        "fr_translate_url": "URL:",
                        "it_translate_url": "URL:",
                        "ja_translate_url": "URL:",
                        "nl_translate_url": "URL:",
                        "pt_translate_url": "URL:",
                        "ru_translate_url": "URL:",
                        "tr_translate_url": "URL:",
                        "zh-CN_translate_url": "URL:",
                        "zh-TW_translate_url": "URL:",

                        "en_translate_blacklistedDomain": `<b>${urlString}</b> is a blocked domain in your antivirus settings.`, 
                        "de_translate_blacklistedDomain": `<b>${urlString}</b> wird aufgrund Ihrer Antivirus-Einstellungen immer blockiert.`,
                        "es_translate_blacklistedDomain": `<b>${urlString}</b> es un dominio bloqueado en la configuración de tu antivirus.`,
                        "fr_translate_blacklistedDomain": `<b>${urlString}</b> est un domaine bloqué dans les paramètres de votre antivirus.`,
                        "it_translate_blacklistedDomain": `<b>${urlString}</b> è un dominio bloccato nelle tue impostazioni antivirus.`,
                        "ja_translate_blacklistedDomain": `<b>${urlString}</b> はアンチウイルスの設定でブロックされたドメインです。`,
                        "nl_translate_blacklistedDomain": `<b>${urlString}</b> is een geblokkeerd domein in uw antivirusinstellingen.`,
                        "pt_translate_blacklistedDomain": `<b>${urlString}</b> é um domínio bloqueado nas configurações do seu antivírus.`,
                        "ru_translate_blacklistedDomain": `<b>${urlString}</b> - заблокированный домен, заданный в параметрах антивируса.`,
                        "tr_translate_blacklistedDomain": `<b>${urlString}</b> etki alaný, antivirüs ayarlarýnýzýn engellenenler listesinde.`,
                        "zh-CN_translate_blacklistedDomain": `<b>${urlString}</b> 是您的杀毒设置中已阻止的域。`,
                        "zh-TW_translate_blacklistedDomain": `在防病毒軟體設定中， <b>${urlString}</b> 是一個封鎖的網域。`,      

                        "en_translate_accessUnblock": "To access it, unblock the domain.",
                        "de_translate_accessUnblock": "Um die Seite zu besuchen, entfernen Sie den entsprechenden Eintrag.",     
                        "es_translate_accessUnblock": "Para acceder a él, desbloquea el dominio.",
                        "fr_translate_accessUnblock": "Pour y accédez, débloquez-le.",
                        "it_translate_accessUnblock": "Per accedervi, sblocca il dominio.",
                        "ja_translate_accessUnblock": "アクセスするには、ドメインのブロックを解除します。",
                        "nl_translate_accessUnblock": "Deblokkeer het domein voor toegang.",
                        "pt_translate_accessUnblock": "Desbloqueie o domínio para poder acessar.",
                        "ru_translate_accessUnblock": "Чтобы зайти на этот домен, разблокируйте его.",
                        "tr_translate_accessUnblock": "Erişmek için etki alanının engelini kaldırın.",
                        "zh-CN_translate_accessUnblock": "要访问它，请解除对域的阻止。",
                        "zh-TW_translate_accessUnblock": "欲對其進行存取，請解除封鎖該網域。",
                };

                var translation_elements = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="translate_"]');
                translation_elements.forEach(function(transItem) {
                                if (transItem.id == "translate_title")
                {
                    var key = translationLang + "_" + "translate_securityWarning";
                                    var translation = translations[key];
                    if (translation)
                    {
                        transItem.innerHTML = "Avira" + translation;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                                    var key = translationLang + "_" + transItem.id;
                                    var translation = translations[key];
                    if (translation)
                    {
                        transItem.innerHTML = translation;
                    }
                }
                        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In WSL I was running python 3.8.  In Windows I use python3.9, using pyenv installed 3.8 in Windows and still nothing.

I'm guessing it has something to do with encoding and decoding but can't figure out what is going on.

I also tried setting utf-8 inside the encode method but it did not change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the HTTP protocol and use `\r\n` for line endings.

```py
import socket

mysock=socket.socket()
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
with mysock:
    cmd = b'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'
    mysock.sendall(cmd)
    data=mysock.recv(4096)
    print(data.decode())
```

Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 14 Nov 2022 03:29:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Sat, 13 May 2017 11:22:22 GMT
ETag: "a7-54f6609245537"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 167
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain

But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
```